# Wildfly 14 How java classes from one EAR file could be accessed by another EAR

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-14

I have two .Ear files, namely ABC.EAR and XYZ.EAR.

ABC.ear has some dependencies on some jars which are in XYZ.ear.

1. I cannot pack them into one .EAR file.
2. I cannot put the used libraries in lib folder of WildFly(WildFly\modules\system\layers\base).

Comment: Is there any pressing reason because of which you can't adopt the strategies you excluded or is it just preference?

Comment: Anyway, I may be misunderstanding the situation, but have you tried with [global modules](https://docs.wildfly.org/14/Developer_Guide.html#global-modules)?

Comment: Why not put the libs into each ear that they require?

Answer (score 0):

> jars which are in XYZ.ear.

If the jars are sub-deployments, you can specify dependencies in jboss-deployment-structure.xml in dependent ear.

E.g. ABC.ear/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.XYZ.ear.xxxx1.jar">   <!-- xxxx1.jar is a sub-deployement of XYZ.ear -->
                <imports>
                    <include path="**"/>
                </imports>
            </module>
            <module name="deployment.XYZ.ear.xxxx2.jar">   <!-- xxxx2.jar is a sub-deployement of XYZ.ear -->
                <imports>
                    <include path="**"/>
                </imports>
            </module>

            <!-- other dependencies here ... -->
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

You can check the list of sub-deployments for the ear in the WF management console: Deployments menu -> select ear -> Subdeployments.

If the jars are just libs (NOT sub-deployments), then you should be able to add the same libs to ABC.ear.